# How to use value in another method

Tags: android, vector

Here i get some value from firebase database,now I want to use this value in another class.what is the actual code for this??

```
 final Vector<String>v_id = new Vector<>();
    final  Vector<String>v_name = new Vector<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    com.google.firebase.database.Query query = databaseReference.child("user").orderByChild("department").equalTo("swe");
    query.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                v_id.add(id);
                v_name.add(name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you want to use them in another class or activity??

Comment: another activity

Answer (score 0):

Try create a **method** in a class like **firebaseutil** class for exemple and call the method in other class like this:

```
    public class firebaseutils {

         public static void getvector(Vector Id, Vector Name){

              DatabaseReference databaseReference =          FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
              com.google.firebase.database.Query query = databaseReference.child("user").orderByChild("department").equalTo("swe");
              query.addChildEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                     for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                String id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Id.add(id);
                Name.add(name);
               }
        }

         }
    }
```

And in other **class/Activity** just **call**:

firebaseutils.getvector(your_vector_id, your_vector_name);